# Animation lagging after some time android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have custom bottom menubar. I am trying to implement animation on view visible. my code is like below

```
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CardMainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_up);
ll_fonttextview.setAnimation(slideUp);
ll_fonttextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and XML like this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Its working fine but after some click, its stop showing animation. I am not getting any error for that. Let me know if anyone have idea to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: show me a error log

Comment: @MohammadAli I am not getting any error.

Comment: ll_fonttextview.clearAnimation() try this before ll_fonttextview.setAnimation(slideUp) .

Comment: @sunilsunny still same issue